# Sending an enum that is a tuple on a dictionary and back

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, tuples, swift5

I am new to Swift, so excuse my ignorance.

I have this enum:

```
public enum ConnectionResult {
  case values(state: MCSessionState, peerID:MCPeerID)
}
```

I put that on a dictionary

```
let dict = ["values" : ConnectionResult.values(state:state, peerID:peerID)]
```

I send this dict over a notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .adjustState, object: dict)
```

When I receive the notification, I want to obtain the `state` and the `peerID` values back

```
@objc private func onAdjustState(_ notification:Notification) {
  if let dict = notification.object as? Dictionary<String,Any>,
  let result = dict["values"] as? ConnectionResult {

}
```

How do I get state and peerID from result?

I have tried

```
let state = result.values.state as? MCSessionState
```

I have tried

```
let (state, peerID) = result  // the thing is a tuple, right?
```

without success...

By the way, is there a way to send this `ConnectionResult` object, that is a tuple, on the notification directly instead of using a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectionResult` is not a tuple. It is an enum with only one case (which kind of defeats the purpose of an enum), so you need to handle it like an enum.

To get `state` and `peerID`:

```
if case .values(let state, let peerID) = result {
    // you can access "state" and "peerID" here
} else {
    // this will never be reached
}
```

As you can probably tell, an enum is not suitable here. I recommend changing to an actual tuple:

```
// create the dict like this
let dict = ["values" : (state:state, peerID:peerID)]

// get state and peerID like this
if let result = dict["values"] as? (state: MCSessionState, peerID: MCPeerID) {
    let (state, peerID) = result
} else {
    // handle "dict["values"] as? (state: MCSessionState, peerID: MCPeerID)" being nil
}
```

or a `struct`:

```
struct ConnectionResult {
    let state: MCSessionState
    let peerID: MCPeerID
}

// create the dict like this
let dict = ["values" : ConnectionResult(state:state, peerID:peerID)]

// get state and peerID like this
if let result = dict["values"] as? ConnectionResult {
    let (state, peerID) = (result.state, result.peerID)
} else {
    // handle "dict["values"] as? ConnectionResult" being nil
}
```

You can send the struct/tuple directly too, without putting it in a dictionary first, because the `object` parameter accepts `Any?`. You just need to cast `notification.object` directly to the struct type or tuple type.